# Is it good practice to call controller methods?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Lest suppose we have couple of controller in Laravel. It is logic business layer that responsibilities about process activity.

One of them is `ProductController`, another one is `OrderController`.

Is is good practice to use selectivity `ProductController's` methods in `OrderController`?

If to lean on the SOLID principies, it is not. But what if I need to use one part of logic `ProductController` in  `OrderController`?

Does it mean that I should use only through HTTP request? Or better to create singleton service, that will be available for both controllers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it's not a good idea. Depending on what functionality you want to share, you could use, for example, the repository design pattern or the presenter pattern. There are some examples around specifically for Laravel using those design patterns.